# Can anyone please explain about the timing mentioned in lockAtLeastFor = "PT1M45S", lockAtMostFor = "PT2M" what is PT here

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, shedlock

Can any one please explain about timing defined in lockAtLeastFor and lockAtMostFor. what is PT1M45S and what other parameters it can accept.

```
  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/2 * * * *")
  @SchedulerLock(name = "TaskScheduler_scheduledTask", lockAtLeastFor = "PT1M45S", lockAtMostFor = "PT2M")
  public void performJob()
  {
     System.out.println("executed");
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is the [ISO-8601 duration format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). The `P` stands for period and is (optionally) followed by a duration in years (`Y`), months (`M`), weeks (`W`) and days (`D`). The `T` stands for time, and is followed by one or more of hours (`H`), minutes (`M`) and (fractional) seconds (`S`).

See also the javadoc of [`Duration.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)). The duration format supported by Java has no support for `Y`, `M` and `W` as specified in ISO-8601, but instead uses a simplified format like `PnDTnHnMn.nS`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [ISO 8601 format for duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

It seems that you are using [ShedLock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock/blob/master/shedlock-core/src/main/java/net/javacrumbs/shedlock/core/SchedulerLock.java).
According to the doc, it can accept duration in ms.

> /**
>        * The lock will be held at least for X millis. Can be used if you really need to execute the task
>        * at most once in given period of time. If the duration of the task is shorter than clock difference between nodes, the task can
>        * be theoretically executed more than once (one node after another). By setting this parameter, you can make sure that the
>        * lock will be kept at least for given period of time.
>        */

long lockAtLeastFor() default -1;

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states:

> Can be either time with suffix like 10s or ISO8601 duration as described in {@link java.time.Duration#parse(CharSequence)}, for example PT30S.

Answer (score 0):

It's specified in ShedLock documentation

> Duration specification
>
> - duration+unit - 1s, 5ms, 5m, 1d (Since 4.0.0)
> - duration in ms - 100 (only Spring integration)
> - ISO-8601 - PT15M (see Duration.parse() documentation)

https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#duration-specification